# Does iOS development have a text layout representation (XML or other)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to iOS development.

I try to build a UI similar to a mokeup I have:

[image]

my try:

[image]

In general, there is no XML or other text file representing the UI? Just drag-and-drop editor in Xcode?

When I set an imageUI element, can I set the image src in the Xcode editor or just via code?

How do I set `UITextField` bg color?

I have tried this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var inline_icon: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    inline_icon.image = UIImage(named: "inline-logo.jpg");

    location_title.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0xdb, green: 44, blue: 36, alpha: 0)
}
```

but my code stopped on this, as if I put a breakpoint there:

[image]

Comment: Not sure why people think this deserved 2 downvotes?

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an XML based if you right click on Main.storyboard and choose
Open as > Source code.

To change the properties of an `UITextField`, see examples below

```
txtField.delegate = self
txtField.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
txtField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
txtField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
txtField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
txtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
txtField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
```

More information about debugging in Xcode can be found at [Apples developer site](https://developer.apple.com/support/debugging/).